# Error using node request library on socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, socket.io, request

I'm using socket io on my laravel project and I have a problem with the request on my disconnect event in the socket.js file.

I have debugged my code and the error is with the request library.

**Socket.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(5000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("new client connected " + socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        var socket_id = socket.id;
        console.log('client disconnected :C '+socket_id);

        var request = require('request');
        var url_request = 'http://example.com/play-session/close?socket_id=' + socket_id;
        request(url_request, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log('session closed '+socket_id);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Error:**

```
SyntaxError: Error parsing /var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/aws4/package.json: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at readPackage (module.js:113:52)
    at tryPackage (module.js:123:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:190:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/request/request.js:11:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

I don't know what is happening. I appreciate all the help, thanks.

**Updated, Fix issue complete:**

I fix this issue with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#unix-domain-sockets, ussing that example like this:

**Socket.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');
var request = require('request');

server.listen(5000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("new client connected " + socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        var socket_id = socket.id;
        console.log('client disconnected :C '+socket_id);

        var url_request = 'http://example.com/play-session/close?socket_id='+socket_id;
        request.get(url_request); // this line fix it
    });
});
```

Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: looks like `aws4` is causing the issue. Try re-installing it

Comment: Ok I will try re-installing the request library again in my server.

Comment: not `request`, but [`aws4`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4)

Comment: haha, ok i will try with this

Comment: Shaharyar, thanks for your help. I fix it

Comment: Was it the `aws4` issue or something else?

Comment: No, was the way to make the request, thank you so much for your help bro..

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#unix-domain-sockets, ussing that example like this:

```
request.get(url_request);
```

Regards